# How to add an Integer object, and an Object, in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to add two objects, one of type Integer, and the other of type ArrayList(i). Here is the function I am working on, I will need to find the average of the array. The error I get is:  error: bad operand types for binary operator '+', for the line 7 here. That sum is of type Integer and a.get(i) is of type Object.

```
 public static int brojDoProsek(ArrayList a){
    //Code here...
    double average = 0.0;
    Integer sum = new Integer(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        sum = sum + a.get(i);
    }

    average = sum / a.size();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the sum of a `Integer` and a `Object` to be?

Comment: @tkausl Integer

Comment: As far as the Java **compiler** is concerned your `ArrayList` could contain anything not just integers - so it is complaining because you can't add any object to an integer. If you use generics and declare your list as `ArrayList<Integer>` then the compiler will know the list contains integers and will be happy.

Comment: @greg-449, I already did that! But it would not work...

Comment: The code you show compiles fine for me using `ArrayList<Integer>` and Java 8. Show us an [mcve]

Comment: @greg-449 I posted it.

Comment: You must specify the generics everywhere so your method declaration must be `public static int brojDoProsek(ArrayList<Integer> a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array<E> {


public static int brojDoProsek(ArrayList a){
    //Code here...
    double average = 0.0;
    Integer sum = new Integer(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        //sum = sum + a.get(i);
    }

    average = sum / a.size();



    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String s = stdin.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(s);

    //Code here...
    ArrayList <Integer> niza = new ArrayList<Integer>(N);

    String b;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        b = stdin.readLine();
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(b);

        niza.add(i, temp);
    }

    System.out.println(brojDoProsek(niza));     
}
```

}